# How to change select tag value when other select is change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My HTML page contents two select options as follows.

[image]

It has two `li` selection as `#age1` and `#age2` with contents 18 to 30 ages.
I want to make it as if user select a age from `#age1`, `#age2` minimum value set to same value(not only pragmatically, even in the display on select). That means user cant see below values than the `#age1` selected value.

Eg:- if user select 25 from `#age1`, `#age2` selector values starts from 25 to 30.

HTML

```
<li>
  <label class="label">Age</label>
  <select id="age1">
    <option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="24">24</option><option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="26">26</option><option value="27">27</option>
    <option value="28">28</option><option value="29">29</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
  </select>
  <label class="label">To</label>
  <select id="age2">
    <option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="24">24</option><option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="26">26</option><option value="27">27</option>
    <option value="28">28</option><option value="29">29</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
  </select>
</li>
```

J-query

```
$("#age1").change(function() {      

});
$("#age2").change(function() {

});
```

Comment: you can use or make a function of jquery to achieve this.

Comment: Lock #age2 until a value is selected on #age1 and filter the <li> tags to display only the ones with value attribute > to the selected on #age1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#age1").change(function() {
    var getStartVal = $(this).val();
    $("#age2").val(getStartVal).find("option").show().each(function() {
      if($(this).attr("value")<getStartVal) {
         $(this).hide();
      }
  });
});
```

You can use the above jquery to make it working.

**Working Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/wpam11k7/**

Comment: You could drop `.show()` and do `$(this).toggle($(this).val() >= getStartVal);`  inside `each` instead.

Comment: oh yeah, this could also be a better option. thanks @vesse

Answer (score 0):

ameenulla0007 answer is a good one but I would edit you html like this

```
<select id="age1">
    <option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="24">24</option><option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="26">26</option><option value="27">27</option>
    <option value="28">28</option><option value="29">29</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
  </select>
  <label class="label">To</label>
  <select id="age2">

  </select>
</li>
```

Then use this jQuery to add just the selections you want rather than hiding

```
jQuery("#age1").change(function() {      

    var bottomEnd = jQuery("#age1").val();
    var topEnd = jQuery("#age1").val() + 30;
    for( $i=bottomEnd; $i < topEnd; $i++ {
        jQuery('#age-2').append('<option value="'+jQuery('#age1').val()+'">'+jQuery('#age1').val()+'</option>');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the html from your first age list to populate the second one, since they appear to be the same:

```
$("#age1").on("change", function() {

  /* get the value of age1 */
    var val = $(this).val();

  /* get all the ages after the selected one
     and add them to the selected age */
  var $selected = $(this).find("option:selected");
  var $available = $selected.add( $selected.nextAll() ).clone();

  /* save the selected value of age2 */
  var selected2 = $("#age2").find("option:selected").val();

  /* append the html from age1 selection to the
    age2 list, and try to keep the old selection value */
  $("#age2")
    .html( $available )
    .find("option[value='" + selected2 + "']")
    .prop("selected", true);

});
```

You can see it running here; https://jsfiddle.net/1qsnzyjh/ :)

Comment: a bonus over the other answers... this one will save the previous selected value if it can, which is a better user experience :)