# automatically change selected option based on manual change of a other select

Tags: jquery, html

I have 2 same selects with different IDs. If i change one the other should change to the same option. Useing Jquery.

```
<select name="quantityMobile" id="quantityMobile">

    <option selected value="1">1 pice</option>
    <option value="2">2 pice</option>
    <option value="3">3 pice</option>
    <option value="4">4 pice</option>

</select>

<select name="quantityTablet" id="quantityTablet">

    <option selected value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>

</select>
```

Comment: ...and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36457921/how-to-change-select-tag-value-when-other-select-is-change and several others. Please search thoroughly before posting. More on searching [here](/help/searching).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use change event handler and update based on the value.

```js
var $ele = $('#quantityTablet,#quantityMobile').change(function() {
  $ele.val(this.value);
  // or $ele.not(this).val(this.value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="quantityMobile" id="quantityMobile">
  <option selected value="1">1 pice</option>
  <option value="2">2 pice</option>
  <option value="3">3 pice</option>
  <option value="4">4 pice</option>
</select>

<select name="quantityTablet" id="quantityTablet">
  <option selected value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: But it did not work with selectboxIt...do you have an issue for that also?

Comment: @NiklasStadler :  can you share the code in http://jsfiddle.net